# How to modify sql table from another table by using where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to update `test1` table some rows. `ColumnC` is zero in test1.

For example:

ColumnA is parent node. ColumnA+ColumnB is primary Key.

```
create table test(ColumnA int,  ColumnB int,  ColumnC int);
Insert Into test Values(1, 10,0);
Insert Into test Values(2, 11,0);
Insert Into test Values(3, 14,0);

create table test1(ColumnA int,  ColumnB int,  ColumnC int);
Insert Into test1 Values(1, 9,123);
Insert Into test1 Values(1, 10,0);
Insert Into test1 Values(2, 10,128);
Insert Into test1 Values(2, 11,0);
Insert Into test1 Values(3, 13,145);
Insert Into test1 Values(3, 14,0);
```

My desired result:

[image]

My not working code:

```
update test1 a 
set a.ColumnC = b.ColumnC
from test1 as b where convert(nvarchar,b.ColumnA)+
convert (nvarchar,b.ColumnB)in(select
convert(nvarchar,c.ColumnA)+
convert (nvarchar,c.ColumnB)  ColumnC  
from test as c);
select * from test1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what about using stored procedure to do this @programmerist?????

Comment: @NetStarter: i dont understand. My code is above

Comment: How about providing example table schemas that actually, you know, help explain the problem/question at hand. Who designs tables with columns named ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC and test1 test2. It not only doesnt help me grok what you are asking, it in fact makes it even harder to answer.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what you want to do?can you explain?

Comment: you want it to be done by a single query or by stored procedure?

Comment: single query what i need. i want to update test1'S 0  values.

Comment: then why do you need test table? why have you mentioned?

Comment: read this link to know hoe to create a stored procedure http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0540__Function-Procedure-Packages/Creatingaprocedure.htm and this one http://www.redware.com/handbooks/sql_server_handbook/sql_server_stored_procedures.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
update a set a.ColumnC=b.ColumnC


from test1 a 
inner join test1 b
on b.ColumnA=a.ColumnA and b.ColumnC!=0
and a.ColumnC=0;


select * from test1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b837f/9)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update table test1, it has to be in your where clause.